# Memcached: Update Notification for Client Caches

Tags: c#, .net, performance, memcached, distributed-cache

Let's take the .NET client of Memcached for example:

As we know, if we want to put some data to the cache server, we call some API like `Cache.Add(string key, object data)`, and the memeched client will serialize the `data` and then send it to the cache servers. If the `data` is a complex object (has a large object graph), the serialization process might be very slow. So, I try to use 2-level cache: **Distributed Cache** and **In-Memory Cache**.

The application code will always ask the In-Memory Cache for the cached data. If the In-Memory Cache does not have the cached data, it will then ask the cache servers for the cached data. The performace can benifit from the usage of In-Memory cache, for In-Memory cache need no serialization operation and is much closer to the application.

However, there's a synchronization problem. If one web server modifies the data, it will update the database, its In-Memory Cache and the Distributed Cache. **But other web servers won't be notified about this "update" event, so their In-Memory Cache won't be updated.**

So the question is: **How can other web servers be notified when one web server updates the data (so that they can update their In-Memory Caches)?** Thanks!

**BTW:** I want to synchronize the cached data in a **"Push Sync"** fashion, that is, the cached data will be updated **only** when they're changed. Because in my application, there are lots of reads while only some writes.

Comment: "might be" is a difficult statement to use to drive architecture around it.  Is it too slow?  Development versions of memcached will do what you're asking for, but I don't think it will scale well on larger caches for lots of front-end servers.  Every write has to get sent to every app server just in case it has the data cached.

Comment: Im interested in this as well but working on PHP, what I have thought of is using Shared Memory in my case but in yours maybe you can set a "public" script to CURL to? http://192.168.1.13/update/?objectid=132